# problem with load nativeStorage at first run

Tags: ionic3

I need help to solve this problem.
   In home.ts I check if user had logged in before with `nativeStorage`

**home.ts**

```ts
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.load();
}

load() {

  this.chk = this.gettoken();

  alert(this.chk)
  if (this.chk == 'true')

  {
    //// code here
  }

  gettoken(): Promise<string> {
    this.nativeStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn').then((value) => {
      this.val = value;
    });
    return this.val;
  };

}
```

and in login page I save to storage using this :

```ts
this.nativeStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn','true');
```

At first time run app I got 'undefined' and it's ok now. After I login successfully  and close the app and run it again I got 'undefined' 
   and I have to go to another page and back again to home page to get the value of storage (`isLoggedIn`) true

I change `gettoken()` to this:

```ts
async gettoken(){
    return await this.storage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
}
```

but the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then you need to wait for `.gettoken()` too, by doing:

```
async load(){
    this.chk = await this.gettoken();
    alert(this.chk);
}
```